# Binary search by a key containing two variables

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I have a sorted array of pairs (x,y) which are sorted by x and for same x they are sorted by y.For clarification an example would be (2,3),(2,4),(3,2),(3,4),(3,5). For a given pair (a,b), I want to find the pair (c,d) such that c>a and d>b such that c and d are minimal. I get the feel that this can be done by binary search but I don't know how. Any help or link regarding the same.

Comment: Given (1,1), array is ((2,3), (3,2)) - which one you need?

Comment: @Arvo minimum x in that case

Comment: You probably want [`std::lower_bound()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the condition `c>a and d>b`, we'll first search for acceptable values of `c`, and then search for minimal `d`.

```
auto compare_first = [](std::pair<int, int> const & a, std::pair<int, int> const & b){
    return a.first < b.first;
};

auto compare_second = [](std::pair<int, int> const & a, std::pair<int, int> const & b){
    return a.second < b.second;
};

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> values { {2,3}, {2,4}, {3,2}, {3,4}, {3,5} };

std::pair<int, int> value { 2, 3 };

auto it_c = std::upper_bound(values.begin(), values.end(), value, compare_first);
auto it = std::upper_bound(it_c, values.end(), value, compare_second);
```

[Live on ideone](https://ideone.com/DssxFs)